# Цвета в Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Я поставил темный фон на сайт, а черный текст сливается с фоном. Как поменять цвет текста так, чтобы не ломать все, что написано в Bootstrap4? (цвет текста в инпутах, кнопках и т.д.)

```
* {color: #fff;}
```

так не сойдет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923686/bootstrap-change-background-color